# Adding a custom fee based on a selected option in WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce Checkout page, I have added a dropdown custom field with many options of "Card type". Some few are free and others cost $0.99 (fee). The calculated fee on checkout page is okay, but when the order is placed, the fee is not added to the order (for commercial "Card type" options).

The code for fee:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_card_fee');

function add_card_fee() {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return; // Do not add the fee when in the admin area
    }
    if (is_checkout()) {
        if (isset($_POST['post_data']) && !(strpos($_POST['post_data'], 'Bestwishes') !== false || strpos($_POST['post_data'], 'nocard') !== false || strpos($_POST['post_data'], 'happybirthday') !== false)) {
            $extra_charge = 0.99; 
            WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Greeting Card Fee', 'woocommerce'), $extra_charge);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the dropdown custom field (in checkout):

```
function add_custom_field_to_checkout($fields) {
    $fields['shipping']['card_type'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label' => __('Greeting Card', 'woocommerce'),
        'options' => array(
            '' => __('Select an option', 'woocommerce'),
            'nocard' => __('No Card', 'woocommerce'),
            'Bestwishes' => __('Best Wishes (Free)', 'woocommerce'),
            'congratulations' => __('Congratulations ($0.99)', 'woocommerce'),
            'happybirthday' => __('Happy birthday (Free)', 'woocommerce'),
            'happyanniversary' => __('Happy Anniversary ($0.99)', 'woocommerce'),
        ),
        'required' => true,
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear' => true
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

On checkout page everything seems fine, like adding fee in the order total and removing fee from the order total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code and it can't work as it is. It requires Ajax and a WooCommerce Session variable.

Here is the revisited complete code *(remove before all your existing related code)*:

```
// Displaying a checkout "select" custom field
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_select_field_to_checkout');
function add_custom_select_field_to_checkout($fields) {
    $fields['shipping']['card_type'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label' => __('Greeting Card', 'woocommerce'),
        'options' => array(
            '' => __('Select an option', 'woocommerce'),
            'nocard' => __('No Card', 'woocommerce'),
            'bestwishes' => __('Best Wishes (Free)', 'woocommerce'),
            'congratulations' => __('Congratulations ($0.99)', 'woocommerce'),
            'happybirthday' => __('Happy birthday ($0.99)', 'woocommerce'),
            'happyanniversary' => __('Happy Anniversary ($0.99)', 'woocommerce'),
        ),
        'required' => true,
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear' => true
    );

    return $fields;
}

// jQuery - Ajax script
add_filter( 'wp_footer' , 'checkout_delivery_script' );
function checkout_delivery_script() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) return;
    
    WC()->session->__unset('selected_card_type'); // Reset 'selected_card_type' session variable
    
    // Jquery / Ajax
    wc_enqueue_js( "jQuery(function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined')
            return false;
        
        // Ajax 
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'select#card_type', function(){
            var selected = $(this).val();
                console.log(selected); // just for testing | TO BE REMOVED

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action':             'selected_card_type',
                    'selected_card_type': selected,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                    console.log(result); // just for testing | TO BE REMOVED
                }
            });
        });
    });" );
}

// Get Ajax request and saving to WC session
add_action( 'wp_ajax_selected_card_type', 'wc_get_selected_card_type_ajax_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_selected_card_type', 'wc_get_selected_card_type_ajax_data' );
function wc_get_selected_card_type_ajax_data() {
    if ( isset($_POST['selected_card_type']) ){
        $selected_card_type = esc_attr($_POST['selected_card_type']);
        
        // Updating 'selected_card_type' WooCommerce Session variable
        WC()->session->set('selected_card_type', $selected_card_type );
        
        echo $selected_card_type; // Return the value to jQuery
    }
    die(); // Always Exit silently
}

// Add a Fee conditionally in checkout
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_selected_card_type_fee');
function add_selected_card_type_fee() {
    if ( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') ) {
        return; // Do not add the fee when in the admin area
    }
    
    // Only on checkout page
    if( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
        return;
    }
        
    // Get 'selected_card_type' WooCommerce Session variable
    $selected_card_type = WC()->session->get('selected_card_type' );
    
    if (isset($selected_card_type) && ! in_array( $selected_card_type, array('bestwishes', 'nocard') ) ) {
        $extra_charge = 0.99; 
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Greeting Card Fee', 'woocommerce'), $extra_charge );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.